# How to republish data source

Tags: tableau-api

I have a published data source that has some custom calculations in it. When I connect to this data source and create new calculated fields, these fields have to be reflected in my published data source. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to republish the data source with the new fields that you created: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/update-published-data-source